# Receive two json objects at once in ajax method jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return two json objects.But i am able to receive only one. Am i doing wrong? Success is just showing 'success' as string when i try to alert this but otherwise in firebug it has value=true
.So, it must show true which is its value and not the variable instead.

I am returning below in which data is receiving but success is not 
showing its value. How should i extract the value of success in 
my $.ajax funtion..

```
 return Json(new { data = obj, success = isSuccess });

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller/Action",
            data: "",
            success: function (data, success) {
                debugger;
                alert(success);

            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending both `obj` and `isSuccess` flag in one object as `JSON`

```
Json(new { data = obj, success = isSuccess });
```

so finally in ajax call success event you will get that wrapper object only, which will have two properties `data` and `success`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/Action",
    data: "",
    success: function (wrapperObj) {
        console.log(wrapperObj.success); // this will be your isSuccess flag.
        if(wrapperObj.success)
        {            
            console.log(wrapperObj.data); // this will be your obj.                 
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get `response` data as a first argument.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/Action",
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.success);
    }
})
```